# 'For' loop in tidyverse filtering

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm doing a project for a university and working on dataset "elo_blatter" from *fivethirthyeight* library. I want to write all statistics for each football confederation, so I wanted to use *for* loop.
My code looks good but it doesn't work.

```
confs <- c('AFC','CAF','CONCACAF','CONMEBOL','OFC','UEFA')

for (i in 1:6) {
    eb %>% filter(confederation==confs[i]) %>% 
        select(elo98, elo15, gdp06, popu06) %>% summary()
}
```

I'd like to get following results:

```
     elo98          elo15          gdp06            popu06         
 Min.   : 631   Min.   : 611   Min.   :  1076   Min.   :1.584e+05  
 1st Qu.:1012   1st Qu.: 964   1st Qu.:  3264   1st Qu.:3.575e+06  
 Median :1262   Median :1225   Median :  6382   Median :1.933e+07  
 Mean   :1249   Mean   :1211   Mean   : 20526   Mean   :8.444e+07  
 3rd Qu.:1515   3rd Qu.:1480   3rd Qu.: 31676   3rd Qu.:4.329e+07  
 Max.   :1787   Max.   :1755   Max.   :118199   Max.   :1.311e+09  
 NA's   :1   

     elo98          elo15          gdp06             popu06         
 Min.   : 891   Min.   : 788   Min.   :  457.8   Min.   :    84600  
 1st Qu.:1205   1st Qu.:1266   1st Qu.: 1173.4   1st Qu.:  2349126  
 Median :1366   Median :1372   Median : 2025.3   Median :  9729954  
 Mean   :1350   Mean   :1361   Mean   : 4469.1   Mean   : 17253651  
 3rd Qu.:1484   3rd Qu.:1512   3rd Qu.: 4926.3   3rd Qu.: 18772579  
 Max.   :1723   Max.   :1737   Max.   :30740.7   Max.   :143314909  
 NA's   :1
```

And so on for each confederation. Has anybody some idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: In general, try to be more specific than "doesn't work". Is there an error? A wrong result? What's wrong? In this case, I think all your calculations are probably working fine, but non-explicit printing is disabled inside for loops, and you don't assign anything. Perhaps try sticking `%>% print` on the end of your pipeline.

Comment: Damn, it's working. It's all because of I didn't use *print* function. Thanks a lot!